# A less known definition of the definite integral of a continuous function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, reference-request

The definite integral of a continuous function can be defined using the *bounded monotone sequence property*: see Osgood's *Functions of Real Variables*, p.110.

([link to full book](http://hdl.handle.net/2027/mdp.39015059770639)) (screenshots: [page 110](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hD5Vk.png), [page 111](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90O8E.png), [page 112](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sRN4.png))

Please can you give some other reference of the same type (or, better, a link or a book where the matter is approached in the same manner) ?

Comment: That seems like the standard definition, not less known.

Comment: @genepeer I meant not the value but the way to obtain it. Can you explain what do you mean by _standard definition_ ?

Comment: This should help: [Darboux Integral](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Real_Analysis/Darboux_Integral)

Comment: @genepeer I think we don't agree on the meaning of the word _same_ referred to two mathematical expositions. For the moment I should prefer to read some other comment.

Comment: As to the title, the approach is essentially the Darboux's one but starts from a sequence of successive refinements of a partition of the interval with the norm converging to zero instead of applying the least upper/greatest lower bound axiom to the set of all partitions (one can divide the interval by $2^n$ pieces ...). Pedagogically, this possibility is rather interesting.

Comment: Not trying to be rude but what exactly is your question?

Comment: @genepeer Do you know the meaning of the word _reference_ ?

Comment: Was the link I gave not a reference? Jeez, sorry I wasted your time.

Comment: @genepeer Be sure that I found your link very interesting but it doesn't explain the matter as Osgood does: see my third comment. I stop here.

Comment: @Tony: *Please* take screenshots or copy down the information yourself into the question, so that your question will still make sense if external content is removed.

Comment: @Zev Chonoles: What about copyright ?

Comment: @Tony: I think this falls under fair use; you're quoting the material to ask a question about it.

Comment: @Zev: I don't agree.

Comment: @Tony: Do you not agree with the *amount* of material covered by the screenshots I took, or do you think that any amount is not allowed to be captured here? Would you be willing to at least paraphrase the material you're asking about?

Comment: @Zev: I think that any amount is not allowed to be captured here, but at same time admit my incompetence about this matter. Please let me know.

Comment: @Tony: [From the US copyright office](http://www.copyright.gov/fls/fl102.html): "The 1961 Report of the Register of Copyrights on the General Revision of the U.S. Copyright Law cites examples of activities that courts have regarded as fair use: "quotation of excerpts in a review or criticism for purposes of illustration or comment; quotation of short passages in a scholarly or technical work, for illustration or clarification of the author’s observations..."

Comment: @Zev: Very well, thank you.

Comment: @ZevChonoles I guess the citation of yours might be regarded as fair too.

Answer (score 4):

One can define a function $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ to be *regulated* if there exists a sequence $\{s_n\}$ of step  functions such that $s_n\to f$ uniformly. Recall that if $s$ is a step function with constants $c_i$ and intervals of partition $[x_{i-1},x_i]$ for say $i=1,\dots, r$ we define its integral as over $[a,b]$ as $$\int_a^b s=\sum_{i=1}^r c_i\Delta x_i$$

One can prove that if $s_n,t_n$ are two sequences of step functions that converge uniformly to $f$ then $$\lim \int_a^b s_n=\lim \int_a^b t_n$$
 by first proving that for each $\epsilon >0$ there exists $N$ such that $n\geq N$ gives $$|s_n(x)-t_n(x)|<\epsilon$$
We then are led to **define** the integral of a *regulated* function as $$\int_a^b f=\lim \int_a^b s_n$$ where $\{s_n\}$ is any sequence of step functions that converge to $f$ uniformly over $[a,b]$.

It is a nice task to show that continuous functions over closed and bounded intervals are indeed *regulated* in the sense of the definition above.

**SKETCH OF PROOF**

Let $f:[a,b]\to \Bbb R$ be continuous, $\epsilon >0$be given. Let $P_\epsilon(y)$ mean  $-$ for each $\epsilon >0$ and each $y\in[a,b]$ $-$ that there exists a step function $s$ such that $|s-f|<\epsilon$ for $x\in[a,y]$. Define $A=\{y\in[a,b]:P_\epsilon(y)\}$

Then $a\in A$ (trivially) and $A$ is bounded above by $b$, so $\sup A=\alpha$ exists.

$(i)$ First, prove $\alpha=b$ as follows. We know $\alpha\leq b$, since $b$ is an upper bound. Suppose that $\alpha <b$. Then there exists a step $s$ such that approximates $f$ within $\epsilon$ over $[a,\alpha]$. Use that $f$ is continuous at $x=\alpha$ to obtain a $\delta>0$ such that $\alpha+\delta\in A$.

$(ii)$ To show $b\in A$, use again that $f$ is continuous, but now at $x=b$.

It is proven that for each $\epsilon >0$ there exists said step function over $[a,b]$.
Now take $\epsilon =1,\frac 1 2,\frac 13,\dots,\frac 1n,\dots $ to obtain said sequence. $\blacktriangle$.

**ADD** In the above, we needn't proceed by contradiction. What we really are doing is proving that for each $\lambda <b$, there exists a $\delta >0$ such that $\lambda+\delta\in A$, thus showing that $\sup A\geq b$, which gives that $\sup A=b$.

Comment: The technical term is *[regulated function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regulated_function)*

Comment: The argument you give for the existence of a step function such that $\lVert s_n - f\rVert_\infty \lt \varepsilon$ is neat. Another approach would be to exploit that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$ so that we can divide $[a,b]$ in $2^{n}$ intervals $I_k$ of length $2^{-n}(b-a) \lt \delta$ with $|f(x) - f(y)| \lt \varepsilon/2$ for all $x,y \in I_k$ with appropriately chosen $\delta$. Or one could directly establish the stronger fact that $f$ is regulated iff right and left limits of $f$ exist for all $x \in [a,b]$.

Comment: @Martin Thank you yet again! I think the proof is the most elementary of them all: it "merely" uses the axiom of completeness.  =D

Comment: In my question I don't see any regulated function.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo Did you read what I wrote? Continuous functions are regulated, and the integral sums the author proposes are just integrals of a sequence of step functions that converge uniformly to $f$.

Comment: I agree but what about the question ? I am finding some reference containing Osgood's language. See [pdf](http://www.math.ku.edu/~lerner/m500f09/Integration%20theory.pdf).

Comment: @TonyPiccolo I have provided you with a personal reference. Now it is up to you to do an appropriate research to get what *you* want.

Comment: I take note, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I *think* you are trying to ask for the distinction between defining the Riemann integral as a limit of supremum and infimum partitions vs just using a fixed *family* of partitions, in this case something akin to the dyadic intervals as Osgood does. The point is that both methods yield precisely the same result when the function $f$ is continuous on the whole interval. In fact Osgood seems to prove this fact calling it the "Convergence Theorem" on the bottom of page 113 to page 114. In other words, the type of partition and which values to sample $f$ at within the partitions are irrelevant. If you try to extend this definition to badly discontinuous functions, you'll get nonsense, whereas with the usual definition, it'll imply the supremum and infimum sums do not agree thereby not being Riemann Integrable.

Comment: One can avoid the dyadic intervals and start from any partition using a sequence of refinements with the norm converging to zero: see [pdf](http://www.math.ku.edu/~lerner/m500f09/Integration%20theory.pdf) pag. 2 (just found). But now let's come back to the question: do you know some other reference about this approach ?

Comment: Also, referring to [pdf](http://www.math.ku.edu/~lerner/m500f09/Integration%20theory.pdf), without continuity you cannot show that L=U, but these limits exist and do not depend from the chosen sequence of partitions. I don't see a nonsense.

Comment: @tony piccolo: take the pro typical dirichlet function: 1 on the rationals, 0 elsewhere. This function is not *Riemann* integrable because the upper and lower sums do not coincide. Yet Osgolds definition when abusively applied to this function will in fact give you a value for the integral, but the value will depend on where you sample the function

Comment: If the function is not continuous, the convergence theorem (p. 113) is not valid.

Comment: Yes it's not continuous as I pointed out by saying "abuse" and "nonsense".

Comment: I cannot follow you: is $I_1=I_2$ for the Dirichlet function ?

Comment: Could you clarify what $I$ is? If you just use dyadics on the interval $[0,1]$ *with no regard for where you sample* you can get any number between 0 and 1. For example for each dyadic interval pick a rational point to evaluate the function at which will give you an integral of 1. Alternatively sample at irrational points to get 0. Mix them up to get something in between.

Comment: I refer to Osgood (p. 111): to define $T_n$ and $t_n$ you don't use _tagged_ partitions, you don't sample. They are upper and lower sums, not general Riemann sums. For the Dirichlet function defined on $[0,1]$, $I_1=1$ and $I_2=0$ absolutely and they are not equal !

Comment: This has nothing to do with how Osgolds defines the integral on page 110, only why for continuous functions the integral has the same value for all sample points. Whereas if you try to extend Osgolds definition to discontinuous functions you run into the issue of nonunique integrals, whereas the Riemann integral by definition would not exist, period.

Comment: Now I realize that till now we did not speak of the same thing. Can one apply Osgood's definition (p. 110) to an arbitrary function obtaining Riemann theory ? The answer is yes. It is enough to use _any fixed_ sequence of partitions with the norm converging to zero. The problem is not banal and the solution not much known. I give you two references: [Sklar](http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdfplus/2309467.pdf) and especially Jingcheng Tong _Partitions of the interval in the definition of Riemann's integral_, Int. Journal of Math. Educ. in Sc. and Tech. 32 (2001), 788-793 (theorem 3).